# JS SpeechSynthesis Problems with the cancel() Method

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, speech-synthesis

i want to use the cancel Method of window.SpeechSynthesis in Chrome, to cut off an Utterance and start a new one (so you dont have to hear all utterances which are still in queue)

```
var test = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("Test");
window.speechSynthesis.speak(test);  
window.speechSynthesis.cancel();
var test2 = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("Test2");
window.speechSynthesis.speak(test2);
```

Expected: Start speech with var test , but cancel it instantly due to cancel().
Then start speech again with var test2 , which should work fine.

Well of course that did not happen. But what happened was nothing. :D
It seemed like calling speak() after cancel() somehow does nothing.

The API Description is the following:

> This method removes all utterances from the queue. If an utterance is
>   being spoken, speaking ceases immediately. This method does not change
>   the paused state of the global SpeechSynthesis instance.

Thx for answers :)

Answer (score 2):

I just faced the same problem, issuing a **speak** after a **cancel** will result in no utterance being spoken.

I added a small timeout (250ms) after the **clear()** call and it seems to work:

```
var sayTimeout = null;

function say(text) {
    if (speechSynthesis.speaking) {
        // SpeechSyn is currently speaking, cancel the current utterance(s)
        speechSynthesis.cancel();

        // Make sure we don't create more than one timeout...
        if (sayTimeout !== null)
            clearTimeout(sayTimeout);

        sayTimeout = setTimeout(function () { say(text); }, 250);
    }
    else {
        // Good to go
        var message = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text);
        message.lang = "en-US";
        speechSynthesis.speak(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work now, using the code you provided.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#speak", function() {

  var test = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("Test");
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(test);
  window.speechSynthesis.cancel();
  var test2 = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("Test2");
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(test2);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="speak">CLICK ME TO HEAR TEXT</div>
```

Comment: Confirmed.  I hear "Test2" in Chrome 76 / Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

```
function texto_a_voz(reproducir, idioma) {

   var synth = window.speechSynthesis;
   var voices = [];
   voices = synth.getVoices();

   var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(reproducir);
   utterThis.voice = voices[idioma];
   utterThis.pitch = pitch.value;
   utterThis.rate = rate.value;

   if (synth.speaking) {
       // SpeechSyn is currently speaking, cancel the current utterance(s)
       synth.cancel();
       setTimeout(function () { synth.speak(utterThis); }, 250);
   }
   else {
       // Good to go
       synth.speak(utterThis);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Taken this code directly out of the examples of the p5speech lib. Maybe this helps as a work around?

```
    function parseResult()
    {
        // recognition system will often append words into phrases.
        // so hack here is to only use the last word:
        var mostrecentword = myRec.resultString.split(' ').pop();
        if(mostrecentword.indexOf("left")!==-1) { dx=-1;dy=0; }
        else if(mostrecentword.indexOf("right")!==-1) { dx=1;dy=0; }
        else if(mostrecentword.indexOf("up")!==-1) { dx=0;dy=-1; }
        else if(mostrecentword.indexOf("down")!==-1) { dx=0;dy=1; }
        else if(mostrecentword.indexOf("clear")!==-1) { background(255); }
        console.log(mostrecentword);
    }
```